# Python: Finding a (string) key in a dictionary that contains a substring

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

In my script I build a dictionary of keys(albums) mapped to artists(values) so that I can do a quick lookup of what artists made what albums. However, I want the user to be able to find all albums which contain a substring. For example a search on "Light" should return

`[Light Chasers] = Cloud Cult` and also `[Night Light] = Au Revoir Simone`

What's the best way to do this? Should I even be using a dictionary?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
[(k, v) for (k, v) in D.iteritems() if 'Light' in k]
```

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of something like this, I just wouldn't have expressed it so elegantly. I secretly was hoping there might be some sneaky more efficient solution though :)

Comment: If performance is critical, memory is cheap, and the record collection changes only rarely, you could build another "index" dict with individual words as keys and list-of-albums-containing-that-word as values. Unless you're doing a lot of lookups and have a truly huge record collection it's probably not worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever just need the first album containing the text, here's a fast way:

```
try:
    return ('[%s] = %s' % (k, D.get(k)) for k in D if search_string.lower().strip() in k.lower()).next()
except StopIteration:
    return 'No matches found'
```